# Storing and Comparing data in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am doing a simple command line court booking program in C.

The booking information for the court consist of the sport, the court label, start time, end time.

Thus the variables are char sport[], char court[], int start_time, int end_time.

I have to store this booking somewhere so if another user makes the same booking, the program will give an error saying the slot is already taken.

I was going to use arrays to store all this booking information, then compare any subsequent bookings with bookings that exist in this array. However that is not possible because C doesn't allow different data types in the same array.

Could anyone please suggest me which most efficient technique I can use to complete this task of storing and comparing the bookings.

Comment: "However that is not possible because C doesn't allow different data types in the same array." - how is that a problem in your situation? (You know of `struct`s, right?)

Comment: a database is traditional....but as Mat mentioned a struct would be appropriate

Comment: I am total 100% beginner in C. I am a native PHP programmer actually. This is my university assignment. Thus, I have hardly any knowledge on what's available in C. And thanks now I know such thing as struct's exist. Please don't downvote me.

Answer (score 3):

The following structure might be useful,

```
struct booking {

 int start_time;
 int end_time;
 char sport[100];
 char court[100];
};
```

You can then declare an array of structures as follows, which can be used to store the details of multiple bookings.

```
struct booking book[100];
```